# Click handler of button

Tags: gwt

I want to add a button and add click handler to it after entering the values in database.
I want that button to be on onSucess of greeting service.
help me

```
public static void edit1(String fnme,String lnme,String clgn,String scn){

  greetingService.enter(fnme,lnme,clgn,scn, new AsyncCallback<String>()
    {   
    public void onSuccess(String result) 
        {
        Window.alert("successfully entered");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        Button bt =new Button("submit");
         RootPanel.get().add(bt);
         bt.addClickHandler(new MyClickHandler);

        }
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 
        {
            Window.alert("fail");
        }

     });


}
class MyClickHandler implements ClickHandler 
{
    public void onClick(ClickEvent e)
    {
      //create();        
     }
}
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the click handler?
Anyway this is what I think you're trying to do:

```
Button bt =new Button("submit");
RootPanel.get().add(bt);
bt.addClickHandler(new MyClickHandler);

public static void edit1(String fnme,String lnme,String clgn,String scn)
{
    greetingService.enter(fnme,lnme,clgn,scn, new AsyncCallback<String>()
    {
        public void onSuccess(String result) 
        {
            Window.alert("successfully entered");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            create();
        }
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 
        {
                Window.alert("fail");
        }

    });
}

class MyClickHandler implements ClickHandler
{
    public void onClick(ClickEvent e)
    {
        // create();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but here i am facing a new problem that how to call non static method from static method

Comment: actually i want to call a jsni method.

Comment: the create() function is my jsni method i want to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyClickHandler` does nothing inside the `onClick()` method. It should work as long as you put code. Try this:

```java
public static void edit1(String fnme,String lnme,String clgn,String scn){

    greetingService.enter(fnme,lnme,clgn,scn, new AsyncCallback<String>() {
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            Window.alert("successfully entered");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            Button bt =new Button("submit");
            RootPanel.get().add(bt);
            bt.addClickHandler(new MyClickHandler() {
                public void onClick(ClickEvent e) {
                    //DO SOMETHING HERE
                }
            });
        }
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            Window.alert("fail");
        }
    });

}

class MyClickHandler implements ClickHandler {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent e) {
        /* OR DO SOMETHING HERE, BUT THAT WILL AFFECT ALL 
         * INSTANCES OF MyClickHandler
         */
    }
}
```